# How to tell if a card is the default payment source in Stripe?

Tags: java, stripe-payments

How can I tell if a card in Stripe is the default payment option, in Java? For example:

```
for ( ExternalAccount source : customer.getSources().getData() ){
    Card card = (Card) source;
    if ( card.???? // how do I know if it's the default payment option
}
```

Or alternatively, can I query for the default payment source?

The reason I'm asking is because I want to display the last 4 digits of a card to the customer to show them which payment option is their current default. But if there's multiple cards, how do I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if you already have a card on file by comparing the `fingerprint` attribute.  It will always be the same.

You can also get at the default payment source directly by utilizing the `getDefaultSourceObject()` method on the Customer object.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/Customer.java#L92

In other words, compare the `fingerprint` you have against the `fingerprint` of the default source and you'll have your answer.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell right now (looking through the docs etc.) it's not possible to tell if a card is the default payment source by examining it. But I missed the option on a customer that lets you retrieve the default payment option (if there is one) directly e.g.

```
ExternalAccount defaultSource = customer.getDefaultSourceObject();
Card defaultCard = (Card) defaultSource; // if it's a card
```

Answer (score 0):

Using latest Stripe SDK, I wasn't able to use `customer.getDefaultSourceObject()`. Here is the code that works for me

```
    String defaultSource = customer.getDefaultSource();
    if (defaultSource != null) {
        List<ExternalAccount> sources = customer.getSources().getData();
        for (ExternalAccount source: sources) {
            if (source instanceof Card && source.getId().equals(defaultSource)) {
                Card card = (Card)source;
                LOG.info("Last-4=" + card.getLast4()...);
                return card;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: May i know what is customer in " List<ExternalAccount> sources = customer.getSources().getData();"

Comment: Customer customer = Customer.list(Collections.singletonMap("email", "alice@bob.com")).getData().get(0);